# erase a simple node and pass by reference or value a node to function

Tags: c, memory, malloc

```
typedef struct node{
    int data;
}NODE;


void erasenode (NODE** lista){
    free(*lista);
}
int main() {
    NODE* test;
    test = (NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    test->data = 5;
    printf("%d\n",test->data); //1
    erasenode(&test);
    printf("%d\n",test->data); //1
    return 0;
}
```

(1) prints 5

(2) still printing 5

Why this happens? i din't free the memory? or when you free the pointer the data still in the memory but the memory is already free for be used later?

and in this one:

```
typedef struct node{
    int data;
}NODE;
void makenode (NODE* node){
    node -> date = 5;
}
void makenode2 (NODE** node){
    (*node) -> date = 10;
}
int main() {
    NODE* test;
    test = (NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    makenode2(&test);
    printf("%d\n",test->data);
    makenode(test);
    printf("%d\n",test->data);
    return 0;
}
```

makenode and makenode2 modified the value of data in test node, so are both passing by reference? how you pass by value in this case?

Comment: freeing an object does not zeroize it just frees it. Accessing an object after it has been freed invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @ouah so the best way is "NULL it" for avoid the undefined behavior?

Comment: freeing an object means you will no longer use it, so you are not supposed to access an object after you freed it.

Comment: If you ran the program under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/), you would find it complaining about your code reading from previously allocated but now released memory.  That's because it is not something you're supposed to do.  There's no guarantee the pointer is still valid; accessing it might crash your program.  There's no guarantee the value pointed at is unchanged; `malloc()` might now be using that space for its own purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to make it simple let's suppose this is our memory

```
-------------------------------------------------
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  
-------------------------------------------------
```

so after executing `malloc()` you are asking the system to give you space in order to use it for instance to store a table of 5 ints

```
            pointer to the space that you have requested
                V
-------------------------------------------------
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  
-------------------------------------------------
                <------------->
                  The space you are allowed to use it and modify it
```

So you can do anything with that space as you have the privilege:
You can store values in it, modify them, etc.

```
            pointer to your space given
                V
-------------------------------------------------
|  |  |  |  |  |5 |2 |25|1 |44|  |  |  |  |  |  |  
-------------------------------------------------
                <------------->
                  The space allowed to use it and modify it
```

when you free that space it returns to the system and at that time you don't have the right to use it

```
            pointer to your space which is not now owned by you anymore
                V
-------------------------------------------------
|  |  |  |  |  |5 |2 |25|1 |44|  |  |  |  |  |  |  
-------------------------------------------------
```

What you are doing is accessing a memory case that you are not allowed to which is **illegal**

so as you are not allowed to access the space, it is a good habit after freeing the space to set the pointer pointing to the space to `NULL`

Moreover if you don't free that space after gaining it  this will lead to what is called **memory leaks**

Concerning your last question: 
any variable passed as a function argument is passed by value in itself even the array name but if it was a **pointer** the variable pointed by it is passed by reference

for instance

```
int function(int* x);
int a=0;
int *p=&a;
```

so when calling the function like this `function(p)`: `p` is passed by value but `a` is passed by reference because `p` holds its address as if it was `function(&a)`

any modification on `a` will be permanent but not for `p`  because the modification only takes effect during the block of the function and after that it will be discarded !

we summarize

before calling the function we have `p` pointing to `a` (`p`---->`a`)

```
p------------->a
```

during the call of the function a copy of `p` will be created let's call it **p'** and this latter will take the place of `p` during the execution of the function (that's why nothing will happen to p)

```
p ------------->a<----------p'
```

after the call, the copy **p'** will be erased

```
p ------------->a
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks men! was very helpful. Now i get it!